# How to show these sets have the following properties?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I had a quiz question about properties of sets and although I thought I did very well in the quiz it turns out that I failed the most important question. Can someone explain why this set is closed,unbounded and what is its closure because I think it is bounded from $1$ and $0$ but I don't get it.

$$S_1=\{(x,y) \vert x,y \geq 0, x+y<1\}$$

and

$$S_2=\{(x,y) \vert x \in [0,2], 2x+y<1\}$$

I know the second set is bounded and not closed but I still don't know how to comprehend and show this.

Comment: Both are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Are you able to draw the two in the plane?

Comment: I think I can but what does that show?

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at $S_1$. Note that $0\leq y$ and $y<1-x$. Since $x\geq 0$ then $1-x\leq 1$ and so $0\leq y\leq 1$. Analogously $0\leq x\leq 1$. And therefore $S_1\subseteq[0,1]\times [0,1]$ which is bounded by the fact that $\lVert v\rVert\leq\sqrt{2}$ for any $v\in [0,1]\times[0,1]$. Similar reasoning applies to $S_2$.

---

Is $S_1$ closed? Consider the sequence

$$v_n=\bigg(0, 1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$$

and note that $v_n\in S_1$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} v_n=(0, 1)\not\in S_1$. Therefore $S_1$ is not closed. Analogously $S_2$ is not closed.

---

Now for the closure. The rule of thumb is that whenever you have some set defined by relationship $f(v)<g(v)$ with $f,g$ continuous, then the closure changes that relationship to $f(v)\leq g(v)$. This of course not always works (especially when there are more conditions involved like in your case), but it is a good way to start. So can you verify that

$$S_1'=\{(x,y)\ |\ x,y\geq 0, x+y\leq 1\}$$

is the closure of $S_1$? Obviously $S_1\subseteq S_1'$ and it is easy to see that $S_1'$ is closed, because it can be written as

$$S_1'=F^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap G^{-1}([0,\infty))\cap H^{-1}((-\infty, 1])$$

for some three continuous functions $F,G,H:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ (can you guess what the functions are?).

The only remaining issue is: is there a closed subset $C$ such that $S_1\subsetneq C\subsetneq S_1'$? Since the (set-theoretic) difference between $S_1'$ and $S_1$ can be written as $\{(x,1-x)\ |\ x\in[0,1]\}$ and each point of the form $(x,1-x)$ is a limit of some sequence from $S_1$ (how to construct such sequence?), then it should not be difficult to verify that that's not possible.

Comment: Basically when do we say a set is closed or bounded and how these apply for these sets?

Comment: @blknt3191 are you saying you don't know definitions? Just google them.

Answer (score 0):

S$_1$ is the region of the triangle (0,0), (0,1), (1,0)
with the line x + y = 1 removed.

It's closure is the original triangular region.
It is bounded by a ball centered at (0,0) of radius 2.